# Spark: How to set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead property in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

In Spark 2.0. How do you set the spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead when you run spark submit.

I know for things like spark.executor.cores you can set `--executor-cores 2`. Is it the same pattern for this property? e.g. `--yarn-executor-memoryOverhead 4096`

Comment: probably spark-submit ... --conf  spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 4096 ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please find example.
The values can also be given in Sparkconf.

Example:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--[your class] \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-exectors 17
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
--executor-memory 35G \  //Amount of memory to use per executor process 
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 \
--driver-memory 35G \   //Amount of memory to be used for the driver process
--executor-cores 5
--driver-cores 5 \     //number of cores to use for the driver process 
--conf spark.default.parallelism=170
 /path/to/examples.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` has now been deprecated:

> WARN spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead' has been deprecated as of Spark
>   2.3 and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.executor.memoryOverhead' instead.

---

You can programmatically set `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` by passing it as a config:

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
        .master('yarn')
        .appName('StackOverflow')
        .config('spark.driver.memory', '35g')
        .config('spark.executor.cores', 5)
        .config('spark.executor.memory', '35g')
        .config('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', True)
        .config('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', 25)
        .config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '4096')
        .getOrCreate()
)
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Comment: I am using spark 2.4.5 version if it is deprecated then why i am getting org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 51 in stage 1218.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 51.0 in stage 1218.0 (TID 62209, dev1-zz-1a-10x24x96x95.dev1.grid.spgmidev.com, executor 13): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 13 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.